# Out the diff file with certain naming standard with an alias

Tags: git

I want to create an git alias to output a diff file with a certain naming convention.

I create an alias like below. Run git diff to HEAD and output the file named Foo.diff

```
[alias]
    diffAlias = diff HEAD > Foo.diff
```

But running this gave me the error:

```
$ git diffAlias 
fatal: ambiguous argument '>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[alias]
   diffAlias = !sh -c 'git diff HEAD > foo.diff'
```